# javascript looping problem

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addbutton() {

    var o = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i=0;i<o.length;i++) 
    {
     var keyword= o[i].innerHTML;
     var regobj = /<a (.*)>(.*)<(.)a>/g;
     keyword = keyword.replace(new RegExp("<br>", "g")," ");
     keyword = keyword.replace(regobj,"$2");
     keyword = keyword.substring(0,100);
     var str = "<br>"+ "<a class='but' target='blank' ";  
     str += "href=\"http://www.google.com.tr/search?q=";
     str += decodeURIComponent(keyword);
     str += "\">ara</a>";
     o[i].innerHTML = o[i].innerHTML + str;

    }
}
</script>
```

addbutton() adds a search button to end of the li tags, but when i run, it's looping for only 43 times. so it's adding the search button for the first 43 li tags. what is your thoughts, why is looping broken?

**edit:**
more information,

-i tried function on a page that contains 131 li tags. and function is working for the first 43 li tag,

-i tried for both of google chrome and firefox, results are same.

i tried to alert(o.length). there is no problem, it return true number, "131".

Comment: Is it a particular browser that it is not working in? Because getElementsByTag name only works in select browsers.

Comment: Well, how many `li` s do you have? What do you get when you output `o.length`? When are you executing this function?`

Comment: +1 I think we need a little debug info here.

Comment: @Wolfy: If it were that `getElementsByTagName` were not supported, it wouldn't be working the first 43 times. :-) @ocanal: Definitely not enough info in this question to really answer it...

Comment: My bet would be that item #44 does not have 100 characters in the string and is excepting on `keyword = keyword.substring(0,100);`.

Comment: anything in firebug/console ? any errors ? did you try alerting the output of o.length ?

Comment: @ocanal: What's the intent of the `decodeURIComponent` part of the function? It's being called *(in theory, that regex won't necessarily do what you expect)* on the text within an anchor tag, which won't be URL-encoded in the first place...

Comment: @Joel: No, `String#substring` is perfectly happy to have the second argument be out of range; it'll just go to end-of-string.

Comment: i forgot to say it, when i try on a page that have 130 li tags, function is adding for the first 43 li tag, it is nonsense, because when i delete some codes in for looping, for that time function is adding button end of the li less than before.

Comment: It's clearly something about the text in the anchors that you're interacting with. It basically **does** work: http://jsbin.com/iyume4

Comment: @ocanal, I think your HTML is broken at LI 44... did you validate the HTML and inspect it? If o[i].innerHTML == undefined; the code breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's certainly a bug on this line:

```
str += decodeURIComponent(keyword);
```

That should be

```
str += encodeURIComponent(keyword);
```

That may be the problem, `decodeURIComponent` may be blowing up on some input text because you're using it on strings that aren't URL-encoded.

Barring that:

You'll need to look at the actual text in the `li` elements as they're being processed. It's clearly not just a numbers thing, [the code](http://jsbin.com/iyume4) works just fine in Chrome.

I recommend using Chrome's Dev tools (Shift+Ctrl+I) to set a breakpoint in the function and walk through it with your actual test data. Or use the [Firebug add-on](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox to do the same.

Comment: thanks @T.J. Crowder, you are right, the problem is about decodeURIComponent.

Comment: but there is another problem i have, when i get innerHTML, naturally it has lots of tags (<a>, <p>, <b>...). i want to clear tags and get the pure text. how can i do that? i used regex for <a> tag but, actually it is not working properly.

Comment: @ocanal: If you search, you should find a solution for that. If you don't, post it as a separate question. Any decent library -- [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) -- should have a function for it, doing it cross-browser is non-trivial (though not *hard*).